# How to display a custom attribute on Cart Page in hybris?

Tags: tags, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a custom attribute whose value I have to display for every item in the cart on the Cart Page. I want to add the attribute in cartItem.tag. Can someone please tell me where should I add the value? I tried adding it in the CartPageController, but could not find an appropriate place to add the value.

I'm completely new to Hybris, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this new attribute belongs to the OrderEntryData type. You can use or create some Populator to add value to this attribute. You should use populators when you want to copy some value from modelObject to dataObject in order to show it whithin the presentantion layer.

Answer (score 0):

Steps you need to follow:

1. Add new attribute on CartEntryModel at item level where, your new attribute value will get store on model
2. Add new attribute in CartData using **beans.xml, which will hold and show value on cart page
3. Create new custom populator by extending commercefacades's "CartPopulator" and populate new attribute value
4. Finally, you can use new attribute directly on cartPage via. cartEntry.newAttribute